# How to remove .js chunks in Nextjs application?

Tags: webpack, next.js, lighthouse

I have this nextjs application and lighthouse keeps telling me to remove unused chunks.

> ```
> …chunks/26c47f1….6971807….js
> 410.0 KiB
> 399.8 KiB
> …chunks/25.91c4046….js
> 437.6 KiB
> 392.5 KiB
> …chunks/30.3fdf525….js
> ```

I don't know how they are generated and I don't know how to remove them. I've searched everywhere and can't find a solution.

How do I remove the unused chunks after build?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should be careful removing those chunks as it can break your build. Those files are a result of code splitting for performance.  They are autogenerated on every build. So you will need to manually delete them on every build, but again, it's **not** recommended to do so.

Lighthouse only test the page you are currently on so you might not be using those chunks on that page but on another page.

---

The appropriate question is - **How to remove unused code prior to build?**

---

#### Browser extensions

Browser extensions can be injecting code that is read by lighthouse and would be considered unused by your application.

You should run lighthouse in *incognito* mode to prevent this and to get the most accurate score - but this would not solve all of your unused code issues.

---

#### Tree shaking and 3rd party libraries

You can do tree shaking with the official [Next.js bundle analyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@next/bundle-analyzer). This can help identify duplicate libraries and to reduce bundle size and chuck sizes.
Tree shaking would help identify issues like the following.

**Example that shows how unused code gets included via a 3rd party library**

This following would include the whole lodash library

```js
import { throttle } from 'lodash'
```

The correct way is to only import what you are using i.e.

```js
import throttle from 'lodash/throttle'
```

*Note: some third party libraries export everything and you cannot only use the portion you need.  You would have to remove such libraries if you want to completely remove unused code.*

---

#### Your own code

The chunks can also be truly unused so you need to find/look for:

- unused `import`
- unused `export`
- unused variables
- `export *` and your not using all of the code
- code that is in your project folders but not used
- conditional code that can't ever be reached - these issues are really common - linter will pick these up

There are some libraries that can find unused code. But for small projects you can just use linting or perform a manual search.

---

#### Dynamic imports

You can also reduce bundle size by [dynamically importing](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import) code that gets conditionally used.

---

#### Food for thought

Lastly, you can still get a 100% lighthouse score even with the unused chunk files. However, you have a lot of unused code so there is likely duplicated or dead code on your end that is in your project that should be removed.

Comment: so I've gone through your suggestions one by one...I was already doing dynamic imports...no duplicated files/folders and no unused code that I could find. I suspect there'll be unused chunks even on a fresh nextjs application. I'm going to test that theory

Comment: I added some more details about next/link and third party plugins that could be causing your issues too.  You can see my post or read the whole thread if you want https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/13646#discussioncomment-144446

Comment: thanks. I've read through the thread. I'll set up a sandbox and attempt to isolate the problem. So far I've cleaned up my code and run several other checks but the unused chunks persist

Comment: Have you gone though your third party libraries? You can open up the file identified in your build by lighthouse and try to identify functions or keywords to help identify where the unused code is located.   It's a bit tedious and hard to read but it's how I find  unused code I cannot identify. Use the unique function or attribute name in a search and see if google can find the library.

Comment: I just did. I think we've found our culprits. AWS and shoelace. Those are the common names I see throughout the unused chunks. I supposed there isn't much I can do at this point. I'm only importing what I need from them but it seems they ship other things too.

Comment: Glad it's working and you're able to get to the bottom of your issues.  The 3rd party tree shaking part is your last issue.  AWS has 3-4 different JS libraries - the new ones allow you to only import what you are using. I've never used shoelace but this popped up first https://github.com/shoelace-style/shoelace/issues/180 - See cherry picking docs - https://shoelace.style/getting-started/installation?id=cherry-picking

Comment: yeah. I think I'm probably going to switch from shoelace atm. From their official docs, I first have to import "@shoelace-style/shoelace/dist/themes/base.css";...and I'm only using a handful of components from there. Thank you for your assistance. I'll explore options and get back to comment out the best way to deal with these chunks.

Comment: I opted for the CDN usage of shoelace and removed the npm import. The shoelace chunk has now vanished. Doesn't show as unused chunk on lighthouse anymore! One down, aws to go!

Comment: Good stuff - aws sdk v3 is tree shakeable - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/index.html - you just install each package independently i.e. npm i @aws-sdk/client-s3

Comment: Thanks! I believe we have solved this now.

Answer (score 0):

Provided your builds get generated into dist folder - change your package.json build script with this command

```
build: "rm -rf dist && next build"
```

Comment: I suppose the build gets generated into the .next folder.  _next/static/chunks/30.3fdf5254b1383374d286.js

cleaned up the dist folder but nothing happened

Comment: ah ok - then change the folder path from 'dist' to wherever these chunks get created

Comment: just did but it appears the chunks are auto generated. the individual unused chunks can't be targeted...and I can't delete the chunks folder entirely because there are other files inside which are needed

Comment: next rebuilds it all so you can delete the whole lot. That's why its good to run a clean before build so it clears the old content.

Comment: okay so I successfully delete the .next folder entirely so it's rebuilt. same issue exists. lighthouse still says unused files (chunks) exists.

Comment: I thought of what you also said and then went through my application from top to bottom. Realised the server cached some packages in node modules folder and also created duplicates. So now I completely remove the nodes_modules folder and then reinstall before build. That has also worked for removing some of the chunks. Thank you